# In Apache spark memory MemoryStore tryToPut what does free mean

Tags: scala, memory, apache-spark

We run out of memory on our standalone spark cluster with multiple jobs.
While investigating we found these message and began to suspect that too little memory is free

```
16/09/23 12:30:38 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_50802_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 5.1 KB, free 233.5 KB)
16/09/23 12:30:38 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 50802 took 9 ms
16/09/23 12:30:38 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_50802 stored as values in memory (estimated size 11.3 KB, free 244.9 KB)
```

In another cluster we typically have free reported as 500MB+ and many log traces on stack overflow show free in GBs.

After analyzing the code it seems this message is misleading. The reported free memory is actually blocksMemoryused

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/MemoryStore.scala

```
if (enoughMemory) {
        // We acquired enough memory for the block, so go ahead and put it
        val entry = new MemoryEntry(value(), size, deserialized)
        entries.synchronized {
          entries.put(blockId, entry)
        }
        val valuesOrBytes = if (deserialized) "values" else "bytes"
        logInfo("Block %s stored as %s in memory (estimated size %s, free %s)".format(
          blockId, valuesOrBytes, Utils.bytesToString(size), Utils.bytesToString(blocksMemoryUsed)))
      } else {
        // Tell the block manager that we couldn't put it in memory so that it can drop it to
        // disk if the block allows disk storage.
        lazy val data = if (deserialized) {
          Left(value().asInstanceOf[Array[Any]])
        } else {
          Right(value().asInstanceOf[ByteBuffer].duplicate())
        }
        val droppedBlockStatus = blockManager.dropFromMemory(blockId, () => data)
        droppedBlockStatus.foreach { status => droppedBlocks += ((blockId, status)) }
      }
```

The documentation states its used memory not free

```
/**
   * Amount of storage memory, in bytes, used for caching blocks.
   * This does not include memory used for unrolling.
   */
  private def blocksMemoryUsed: Long = memoryManager.synchronized {
    memoryUsed - currentUnrollMemory
  }
```

Question is why is this called free if its actually used memory or am I mis interpreting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, which have been [fixed](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/11899/files#diff-870cd3693df7a5add2ac3119d7d91d34R140) (in a PR containing many other changes) in Spark 2.0.

Indeed the reporting is simply wrong, displaying occupied memory and not free memory.

Comment: Thanks that PR proves my concern